# Xamarin MediaElement: Disable standard popup on MediaFailed

Tags: c#, xamarin

For some reason I have sometimes problems with the video files I want to play with the MediaElement video player. This is, why I created a MediaFailed method:

```
    public void OnMediaFailed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", "My Error Message", "Close");
             Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }

<xct:MediaElement 
    x:Name="Videoelement"
    ShowsPlaybackControls="True"
    Aspect="AspectFit"
    MediaFailed="OnMediaFailed"
/>
```

This works fine. However there is a standard error popup message "Can't play this video". This standard popup always pops up on top of my costum popup. Is there a way to disable the standard popup?

Here is a Screenshot of the standard popup message:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZkK5.png)

Comment: `However there is a standard error popup message "Can't play this video"` What does this popup message  look like? Can you post a screenshot?  Is there any log  about this problem?

Comment: I added a screenshot to my original post. The problem is that I can't find code which causes this popup to show up. I would like to remove it and set my own popup message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `SetOnErrorListener` in your `VideoPlayerRenderer` and override the `OnError` method,let it return `true`,

just as folows:

```
 class VideoPlayerRenderer : ViewRenderer<VideoPlayer, Android.Widget.RelativeLayout>,MediaPlayer.IOnErrorListener
 {

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<VideoPlayer> e)
    {
         ....
         videoView.SetOnErrorListener(this);
    }

    public bool OnError(MediaPlayer mp, [GeneratedEnum] MediaError what, int extra)
    {
        return true;
    }
 }
```

Refer: [Hide "Can't play this video." Alert for Xamarin Android VideoView Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807410/hide-cant-play-this-video-alert-for-xamarin-android-videoview-player) .

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understood the idea but did not get it to work because I don't have an own VideoPlayerRenderer class. I used the the videoplayer from the xamarin community toolkit but have no idea yet how to change the renderer. I am trying to find out how to set it up ( I am building a multi playtform app (iOs and Android)) but I did not find a solution yet.

Comment: You can try to add it into the [Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction) .

Comment: Thanks for your help! I understood it better now, but could not make it yet. What I understood:
I have to create a class in my main project like: 
public  class VideoCostumPlayer : Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.MediaElement

Then I have to make 2 custom renderers for ios and android like this for android:
class VideoPlayerRenderer : ViewRenderer<VideoPlayer, Android.Widget.RelativeLayout>,MediaPlayer.IOnErrorListener

What are "VideoPlayer" and "Mediaplayer" in this context? Videoplayer = Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.MediaElement? For Mediaplayer I have no clue.